# What is the size or length of "Number" datatype used in mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose, database-schema

**Example Schema:**

```
user
{
name: String,
email: String,
phone: Number
}
```

"What is the size or length of the field **phone** with datatype **NUMBER**"

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you set the property to for an initial value, `Number` is either a 32-bit integer or a 64-bit float in the MongoDB document.

But storing phone numbers as actual numbers is typically a bad idea.  Better to store them as strings to accommodate phone numbers of arbitrary length.